# how to export const db = firebase.firestore()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how can I export and import firebase database?
When I do export const db = firebase.firestore(), an error will show me this message:

```
ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 10:0-32
Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package C:\Users\sapic\OneDrive\Plocha\Revizor\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in C:\Users\sapic\OneDrive\Plocha\Revizor\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\sapic\OneDrive\Plocha\Revizor\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
```

Using Firestore, React, NPM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example

**Export**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
export const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
```

**Import**

```
import { auth, db } from '../../app/firebase'
```